# Scripting import of TTF font in order to use with PHP/CSS

Tags: php, fonts

I am used to importing Google texts with scripts in PHP, but now I have downloaded a TTF, or, True Text Font file.

I couldn't find answers about TTF's and PHP scripts specifically.  Can I use a script to bring in a font file saved in my project folder, as I would with a CSS style sheet?

I am using CSS and not CSS3, so I am not sure whether I should be using the @font-face function?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

TrueType does work, though not very well with [Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/ttf).  To use it, you'd put this is your CSS:

```
@font-face { font-family: myFontName; src: url('/path/myFontName.ttf') format("ttf")};
```

The fact you're using PHP doesn't matter at all.  It's all an issue with what browser the user has.

Comment: Ok, I will try this out, thank you.  I have not enough reputations to upvote your answer, but pretend like I did.

Comment: Hehe, ok.  If it does work, you should be able to check the answer as correct even if you can't upvote (I think).

Answer (score 0):

If your file is local and not working intented:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont'; 
    src: local('LiberationMono-Bold'),url('App/Views/css/fonts/LiberationMono-Bold.ttf')
}
```

In my case:LiberationMono-Bold.